# Moving a complicated XAML binding to a Style Setter

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm using a checkbox with a custom style and control template.  I would like to move the height and width bindings over to the style as well, but I can't seem to get it right.

Here's the checkbox XAML

```
<CheckBox Style="{StaticResource MyCheckStyle}"
      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
      Height="{Binding FontSize, 
                       Source={x:Static gap:Settings.Default},
                       Converter={StaticResource MyMathConverter},
                       ConverterParameter='x+10'}"
      Width="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
      IsChecked="{Binding ValueT, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" 
      />
```

- I'm trying to achieve a check box whose height in pixels is 10 larger than the current font size in points (a hack but please ignore that for now).
- I'm binding Width to ActualHeight so that they'll always be square (my custom template would allow any size otherwise)
- I'm using a converter (Ivan Krivyakov's [MathConverter](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/239251/MathConverter-How-to-Do-Math-in-XAML)) to do the math.
- The size I'm binding to is stored in a static instance of a Settings class generated from a Settings file.

MyCheckStyle is currently as follows:

```
<Style x:Key="MyCheckStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MyCheckBoxTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

So far, this all works perfectly.  But my attempt at moving the *Width* Binding to the style crashes the application:

```
    <!-- WIDTH BINDING.  CAUSES A CRASH DUE TO ACCESS VIOLATION -->

    <Setter Property="Width">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Binding>
                <Binding.Source>
                    <RelativeSource Mode="Self"/>
                </Binding.Source>
                <Binding.Path>
                    <PropertyPath Path="ActualHeight"/>
                </Binding.Path>
            </Binding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

My attempts at the moving the *Height* binding are a complete failure. I can't figure out how to replicate the "x:Static" markup extension in element syntax, among other things.   Intellisense/ReSharper isn't helping me much.

```
    <Setter Property="Height">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Binding>
            <!-- NO IDEA WHAT TO PUT HERE? -->
            </Binding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>
```

Anyone able to set me right? Is what I'm doing possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you ever done

```
Prop="{Binding Source={RelativeSouce ...}}"?
```

Nope. It's not Source, it's RelativeSource. The curly brace markup-extension syntax sets the same properties as the XML element syntax, but with curly braces. That's all. If it's RelativeSource with curly braces, it's RelativeSource with angle brackets.

```
<Setter Property="Width">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Binding>
            <!-- RelativeSource, not Source -->
            <Binding.RelativeSource>
                <RelativeSource Mode="Self"/>
            </Binding.RelativeSource>
            <Binding.Path>
                <PropertyPath Path="ActualHeight"/>
            </Binding.Path>
        </Binding>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

For `x:Static`, that's another markup extension (a subclass of [`System.Windows.Markup.MarkupExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.markupextension(v=vs.110).aspx)). If markup extension class names have the `Extension` postfix, the XAML parser lets you omit the "Extension" part. So as it happens [that class is actually named `StaticExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.staticextension(v=vs.110).aspx). If you want static member `Foo.Bar` in the `local` namespace, easy:

```
<x:StaticExtension Member="local:Foo.Bar" />
```

[The `Binding` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding(v=vs.110).aspx) is a subclass of `MarkupExtension` (via `BindingBase`), which is why you can use the curly-brace syntax with it. However, it doesn't have the "Extension" name postfix. That's optional. There's no particular consistency there.

Key point: **Every one of these things is a class**. XAML is a notation for instantiating instances of classes and initializing their properties with either scalar values, or with other class instances. Curly-brace markup extension syntax is a funny little addition -- but a useful one, as you can see comparing the XAML above with what I'm about to suggest as a replacement.

Now, that's all well worth knowing, but you don't need any of it here.

### tl;dr

```
<Setter 
    Property="Width" 
    Value="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
    />
<Setter
    Property="Height"
    Value="{Binding FontSize, 
            Source={x:Static gap:Settings.Default},
            Converter={StaticResource MyMathConverter},
            ConverterParameter='x+10'}"
    />
```

Done.

Comment: Grrr.... (bangs head on desk).  That last bit is *exactly* what I thought it should be!  I only went to the element syntax when I couldn't make it work.   I literally thought that I had tried exactly what you had posted.  Clearly not because... well... here we are.  I screwed it up and went down on a pointless tangent.  I feel awfully dumb for having even asked this question.  Thank you for your time and your patient explanation.

Comment: @Joe That's WPF. You get it 99% right and as far as you can tell it's 100% wrong.